# How to set the $Display variable for website application?

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

I am running tk8.6 with Ruby 1.9.1 on a Solaris box (with no display, only a console).  I have tk and tcl all fully configured and installed.  The website is up and running and runs other applications fine.  The only thing missing is that I want a button on my website to do a calculation and then prompt the user with a tk window from ruby.

The error is that I get a message saying that...

```
 tcltklib: fail to Tk_Init(). no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable (RuntimeError)
```

I know I have to change the $DISPLAY variable, but to what?  It will be a different display each time a different user clicks on the button from their respective browsers...

Comment: If you want a pop-up dialog on your website you should use Javascript for that. Sad but true.

Answer (score 2):

If your website could launch a program on your computer, e.g. tk, then your website could launch the program `rm` and do `rm -rf` to erase your whole hard drive. Or a website could run the text editor on your computer and fill your hard drive with 1 billion files containing spam.  Or the website could start your email program and send each of your contacts 1,000 spam emails.  As a result, a website is not allowed to launch any applications on your computer.

So when you say:

> The website is up and running and runs other applications fine

...the applications are certainly not on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use tk in a web application. Period.